# How to set Secure Flag for.AspNetCore.Antiforgery?

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies

I am using .net core 3.1 on my project. I set Secure flag true for every cookie but I can not set Secure flag for AspNetCore.Antiforgery.

```
services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
});
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can set secure flag for `AspNetCore.Antiforgery` like following:

```
 services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.SecurePolicy =CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        });
```

Remember to clear the previous cookies first.

Result:
[image]

Comment: What will the user experience be if the app is already in the wild and this change is made. Can't easily make end-users delete the cookie.