# Set Https Header Cookies Secure Flag

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, .net-6.0

I am using .net6 with IIS. I am having a problem where secure flag only available on Respond Cookies rather than the request Cookies.

[image]

Did I miss anything?

I have configure the cookies in the program.cs as follow :

```
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
options.Cookie.Name = "WSP";
options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
options.SlidingExpiration = true;`
});
```

I have also add in the following under form

```
<httpCookies requireSSL="true" secure="true" />
```

Comment: what framework are you using? asp.net core? classic asp.net?

Comment: As stated I am using .net6 with IIS.

Comment: but you say you are using a `form`

Comment: sorry for confusing, I added the code under the razor form, <httpCookies requireSSL="true" secure="true" />

Answer (score 0):

I realise that it was the anti-forgeory token which was set as secure. So I have refer to this answer to solve the problem.
[How to set Secure Flag for.AspNetCore.Antiforgery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65199590/how-to-set-secure-flag-for-aspnetcore-antiforgery)